# How to compose this SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, dataset

I studied some SQL but I forgot everything and now I'm trying to do this database schema:

[image]

And I want to subtract of (all `INGRESADO` - all `CANTIDAD`) and return a unique value, something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(ingresado) - SUM(cantidad) FROM Nomina, Gasto;
```

But I think, it's not returning the real value I want...

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
DECLARE @nomina FLOAT;
DECLARE @gasto FLOAT;
SELECT @nomina = SUM(ingresado) FROM Nomina;
SELECT @gasto = SUM(cantidad) FROM Gasto;
SELECT @nomina - @gasto;
```

This return the value I want, but I want it in a unique query, THANKS.

Comment: How do the 2 tables relate?  I can't tell from the field names above.

Comment: I don't need to relate those tables so... I think it's fine like this, I wanted to make this application so simple in order to have to improve later, this is for my personal purpouse and I want to edit it later, and probabbly I will relate it and add new tables, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ( SELECT SUM(ingresado) FROM Nomina ) - ( SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM Gasto ) as Delta
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT(SELECT SUM(ingresado) FROM Nomina - SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM Gasto)
```

Comment: This is correct, but It should be `SELECT ((SELECT SUM(ingresado) FROM Nomina) - (SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM Gasto));` Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

```
Select (SELECT SUM(ingresado) from Nomina) - (select SUM(cantidad)) FROM Gasto);
```

Check this: [How to SUM and SUBTRACT using SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715095/how-to-sum-and-subtract-using-sql)

Comment: Here you have got cross (Cartesian) join and as reason wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't relating the 2 tables, and you just want to subtract the 2 sums, then this should work:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(ingresado) 
   FROM Nomina) - 
   (SELECT SUM(cantidad)
   FROM Gasto)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do two separate queries and then do the substraction inside your code. Like:

```
SELECT SUM(ingresado) FROM Nomina;
SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM Gasto;
```

Then you do the substraction in your code.

I'm sure it would also be possible to do the substraction directly inside the SQL, by using some nested queries, but thats only hassle without advantage.

Comment: Yes I knew that solution, but I needed to be in only one query because I'm using typed-dataset (I don't know if right typed) so I'm doing it through visual studio settings, in order to have less code and cleaner my application, and mvc way.