# how to subtract in sql using php

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I would like to subtract the quantity in my database using php

part of HTML code

```
<label class="control-label">Medicine Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="medname">
<label class="control-label">Quantity</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="quantity">
<button type="submit" class="btn" style="background:#830006;" name="submit1">OK</button>
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
  $mediname = pg_escape_string($_POST['medname']);
  $tits = pg_escape_string($_POST['quantity']);

  $quirt = ("UPDATE medicine_invent set med_stock = med_stock - $tits where med_name = $mediname");
  $sq = pg_query($quirt);
}
```

please help me. i'm still a beginner at php. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No error appearing?

Comment: Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715095/how-to-sum-and-subtract-using-sql) will help you. (10 sec. google)

Comment: first select the current quantity of med_stock then subtract it with $_POST['quantity'] and finally update that quantity.

Comment: no error. but nothing happens in my database

Comment: Thanks a lot @MaximilianFixl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to SUM and SUBTRACT using SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715095/how-to-sum-and-subtract-using-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the $mediname is string you should use quote around this var   (string var)

```
 ("UPDATE medicine_invent 
       set med_stock = med_stock - $tits 
       where med_name = '$mediname'");
```

Anyway you should not use php var directly in your sql code for avoid sqlinjection risk  .. check for you framework/dbdriver the correct use of parametrized  query and pass the value you need  using binding param features

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. i got an idea now. thank you very much.

Comment: @JasonRonda then you should give him 1+ ;)

Comment: Hello sir,
@scaisEdge then why you do not quoted this => `med_stock - $tits`

Comment: @Rits   ..  the number don't need  quotes ... the string need quotes . .. this is the fact ..

Comment: but when i pass quotes to number it inserted,
but why we not use quotes here?

Comment: @Rits  the number is inserted  because the sql engine perform a direct cast do   the fact there is an aritmetic operation involved  but fur a correct use (and a correct understanding of the difference between numeric and string variables) the number var not no must be written in quotes ..  .. Anyway the comments of another answer  are not the proper place for answer  a new  question .. If you need   more post a new properly documented  question

Comment: no brother i just wanted this, and many thanks -- m giving you upvote its same as give you on new question.