# Need MYSQL uquery solution

Tags: mysql

I have the folowing tree tables one is the stock_items with all the items in it. The stock_in has the stock movements in to the stock and stock_out has the out movements:

[image]

and I want to get such a query result:

[image]

could some one help me to make this query?

Comment: Please post sample data, expected outcome and the code you have so far as text to the question and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Next time please don't post images. Paste the data as formatted text instead. Please read:  [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select the stock items and join the in totals and out totals. Aggregate to get the totals. Outer join to get items with and without transactions. Use `COALESCE` to replace nulls with zeros.

```
select
  s.barcode, s.item_name,
  coalesce(si.total, 0) as amount_in,
  coalesce(so.total, 0) as amount_out,
  coalesce(si.total, 0) - coalesce(so.total, 0) as balance,
  s.unit
from stock_items s
left join
(
  select barcode, sum(amount) as total
  from stock_in
  group by barcode
) si on si.barcode = s.barcode
left join
(
  select barcode, sum(amount) as total
  from stock_out
  group by barcode
) so on so.barcode = s.barcode
order by s.barcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join tables using the barcode column?

```
select * from stock_items 
join stock_in on stock_items.barcode = stock_in.barcode
join stock_out on stock_items.barcode = stock_out.barcode
```

Just replace the `*` with a list of desired column names

Comment: I wonder if stock_in and stock_out are summarised movements - op doesn't say..

Comment: I have made changes in op regarding to this question. We need to sume

Answer (score 0):

Unleash the power of [subqueries](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/) and then use [subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715095/how-to-sum-and-subtract-using-sql) to compute the total stock level.

Basically the strategy here is to:

1. Run one query to sum up the total stock in
2. Run another query to sum up the total stock out
3. Run a final query subtracting the summed values.

```sql
select *, (stock_in - stock_out) as total from (select
    product_id pid,
    product_name,
    product_unit,
    (select sum(stock_in) from stock_in where product_id=pid) as stock_in,
    (select sum(stock_out) from stock_out where product_id=pid) as stock_out
from products) summed
```

SQL fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v95qsALSfnm66HoQb6PqJ6/0

Comment: This works perfect how you made it! I have forgotten to tell that in stock_in and stock out there could be  more same product_id-s. What we need to sum some howe and show in the finale query the sum in and out and the diference of the two.

Comment: I uploaded the new spreadsheet

Comment: @TóthLászló I have updated my code and explanation to address this new information